# Update background after all items have loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this problem that my web app loads a large image as background. It is applied in the `<style>` tag on top  of the `body` tag. It works but when the page is opened a white background is shown while the image loads.

I want that be able to set the `background-color` to a specific blue color while the image loads, so I did this:

before the body end tag:

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).foundation();
        $(document).ready(function() {
            document.body.style.backgroundImage="url('img/form_bg.jpg')";
            //$('body').css('background-image', 'url(img/form_bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed');
        });
    </script>
```

However this code wont works and the background wont load. This one sticks:

```
body {
    /*background:transparent;*/
    background-color:#2f3255;
}
```

How can I achieve this:

1. Make the background-color: #2f3255 while the image loads
2. When image is loaded, change the background to image

Comment: try to look at the js console... do you see any error?

Comment: Try using the FireBug extension and pay close attention to the "Net" tab. It may be the case that you have the image location or file name incorrect. http://getfirebug.com/

Comment: There is no Error 404 in the firebug console (Network)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an extra div in the DOM (`#intro`), that covers the whole screen while the background image gets loaded:

CSS:

```
#intro {
   width: 100%;
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   z-index: 100;
   background-color:#2f3255;
}
```

Then, when the page loads, just hide that div:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    // You could add a time out here if you like (setTimeout(function() { $('#intro').fadeOut();   }, 500))
    $('#intro').fadeOut();    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can preload the image and apply it when it's downloaded, like this:

```
var backgroundImage = new Image();
backgroundImage.onload = function() {
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + this.src + "')";
}
backgroundImage.src = 'img/form_bg.jpg';
```

The first download caches the image, so the second time the browser tries to request it and apply it as background, it takes it from there.
Also, if the image is already cached from previous requests, "onload" triggers immediately. You don't have to wrap it in the "body.onload" function or "$(document).ready()" if you want it to be visible even if the page is still loading.

Edit: Here's a jsfiddle - [link](http://jsfiddle.net/9406479s/)